# need help in understanding errors using struct in C

Tags: c

I am trying different ways of working with struct values but all of them give me error.
So,
I have the following global struct:

```
struct Car_ {
    char *currentCar;
    char **cars;
}carPars;
```

then I am truing to assign *currentCar member to point to the first array of **cars.
I am doing it in the following way:

```
tokenizer->currentToken = tokenizer.tokens[0];
```

This tells Member reference type 'struct TokenizerT_' is not a pointer; maybe you meant to use '.'?

Then I try in this way

```
carPars.currentCar = carPars.cars[0];
```

but when I run my program this actually gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS (this usually means segmentation fault).

Then I try :

```
(*curPars).currentCar = (*car).currentCar[0];
```

but then I have - 
Indirection requires pointer operand

How would I do it in correct way?

Comment: Since **cars is a pointer to a list of pointers, you will need to have a pointer to the memory area that contains char pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to assign memory to cars, the number of arrays you want. Lets say 10:

```
cars = (char**)malloc (10*sizeof(char));
```

Then you have to assign memory to each 10 array. Lets say that in each array you want 10 elements:

```
> for (index = 0; index< 10; index++)
>      cars[index] = (char*) malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

Then, to assign to CurrentCar, you can do:

```
carPars.currentCar = carPars.cars[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign something to `cars` first. Presumably you want it to be an array, say of 50 elements:

```
carPars.cars = calloc(50, sizeof (char*));
```

Comment: ok, got it. Need to allocate memory first. But the what syntax would I use to make proper assignment???

Answer (score 1):

you haven't initialized your second member of the carPars variable of type struct Car_. Since there is not any value stored in the double pointer **cars. You may try the following:

```
 carPars.cars = NULL;
    carPars.currentCar = carPars.cars[0];
```

if still it doesn't work you may try this:

```
carPars.cars = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    carPars.currentCar = (char)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

here I am assuming that you want to store 10 cars and each car name consists of 10 characters maximum.
you can change this value as per your need.